# Pushing keys and their values from an object into a 2D array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

This is the object I need to convert to an array:

```
{
    "09:00AM - 09:30AM": "booked",
    "09:30AM - 10:00AM": "notbooked",
    "10:00AM - 10:30AM": "booked",
    "10:30AM - 11:00AM": "notbooked",
}
```

Here's the desired output:

```
[["09:00AM - 09:30AM","booked"],
 ["09:30AM - 10:00AM","notbooked"],
 ["10:00AM - 10:30AM","booked"],
 ["10:30AM - 11:00AM","notbooked"]]
```

I know I can use this for a 1D array with either key or value:

```
angular.forEach($scope.slotss , function(value, key) {
    this.push(key);
},$scope.times);
```

Comment: `Object.keys(obj).map(key => [key, obj[key]])`

Comment: `Object.entries(obj)` ... done :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply wrap your key and value  with `[]`

```
angular.forEach($scope.slotss , function(value, key) {
            this.push([key,value]);
        },$scope.times);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this:

```
var newSlots = [];

angular.forEach($scope.slotss, 
                function(value, key) {
                    newSlots.push([key, value]);
                });
```

Comment: thanks for answering, used Suresh's answer that works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using only javascript we can do like this.

Use `for..in` to loop over the object. Then create a temporary array to push the key and value from the object. Then push this array to the final array

```js
var curObject = {
  "09:00AM - 09:30AM": "booked",
  "09:30AM - 10:00AM": "notbooked",
  "10:00AM - 10:30AM": "booked",
  "10:30AM - 11:00AM": "notbooked",
};
var newArray = [];

for (var keys in curObject) {
  var tempArray = [];
  tempArray.push(keys, curObject[keys]);
  newArray.push(tempArray)
}
console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: thanks for answering, used Suresh's answer that works for me